# Adding Controls to TableLayoutPanel Cell

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm trying to dynamically add controls to very specific cells in my TableLayoutPanel. If I'm not mistaken, the format of the code to accomplish this is the below:

```
Dim Label1 as New Label
Dim x as integer = 0
TableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = TableLayoutPanel1.RowCount + 2
TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(New RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 25))
Label1.Text = "Testing This Label"
TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(Label1, Column, Row)
x += 1
```

So I have the following code:

```
TableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 4
TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(Label1, 0, 0)
```

So far, so good. The Label is successfully added to Column(0) and Row(0). Now, I try to add one more

```
x = 1
Dim Label2 as New Label
Label2.Text = "Testing 2"
TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(Label2, 0, x)
```

And the result is that even though I've defined that Column(0) and Row(x = 1), Label2 is being added to 0, 0. Anyone have any ideas?

**[Edit] Some more information:**

```
TableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 4
TableLayoutPanel2.ColumnCount = 2
```

This TableLayoutPanel is empty with the exception of Label1 and Label2 which are being added programatically.

Comment: What's the value of "x" when you add the label?  A TableLayoutPanel cell can only have one base control.

Comment: the value of x when I add Label2 is 1.

Comment: Without you telling us what the RowStyles look like there is no way for us to guess where they should show up.

Comment: @HansPassant Do you mean how many rows there are? The TableLayoutPanel.RowCount = 4 and the .ColumnCount = 2.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.rowstyles(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @HansPassant Ah, I see. The RowStyle is set to Percent.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning here that rows are also being added dynamically. I thought I had that in my original post, but I guess I forgot. I updated my original post.